# Filter the NIFI logs for monitor the nifi-application

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, unix, apache-nifi

For NIFI by default, monitoring is not there. I am trying to filter the ERROR and processor information from the nifi-app.log file. From the Unix command, I can see the below format for the error logs in NIFI.

```
2022-08-04 23:39:13,790 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.processors.kudu.PutKudu PutKudu[id=b0fb3488-6c64-1d43-8c99-eada1eb75718] Failed to write due to Row error for primary key="ce70cb52-1c1e-4dd4-a8e1-3fb658dfef45\x00\x00c23e26d7-144f-4f5b-b47e-f9fe0050af30\x00\x00\x80\x00\x01\x82l\x9A\xA3\x90", tablet=null, server=null, status=Not found: ([0x0000000280000181B70EA800, 0x000000038000000000000001))
```

Above Logs I filter from the command :
`cat nifi-app.log | grep ERROR`
in above log :
Time - 2022-08-04 23:39:13

Log level : ERROR

Processor :  PutKudu

Processor_id : [id=b0fb3488-6c64-1d43-8c99-eada1eb75718]

Exception : Failed to write due to Row error for primary key="ce70cb52-1c1e-4dd4-a8e1-3fb658dfef45\x00\x00c23e26d7-144f-4f5b-b47e-f9fe0050af30\x00\x00\x80\x00\x01\x82l\x9A\xA3\x90"

I passing the input file to python script and trying to filter the info in above format but seems the data not coming, I am using the below command in script.

```
            time = re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', content).group()
            log_level = content.split("~")[1]
            processor = content.split("~")[2].split("[id=")[0].split(" ")[len(content.split("~")[2].split("[id=")[0].split(" ")) -1]
            processor_id = content.split("~")[2].split("[id=")[1].split("]")[0].replace("]","")
            if len(content.split("~")[2].split("]")) > 0:
              message = content.split("~")[2].split("]")[1].replace(",", ":")
```

I want the output in a new file in the below format :
 `print(log_level + "," + processor_id + "," + processor + "," + message + "," + date + "," + time)`

Answer (score 0):

- Navigate to conf directory
- Edit logback.xml
- Add below log appender
- Towards the end of the file, below the closure of configuration XML tag, add appender-ref
- Use ExtractGrok NiFi processor to consume the log data from custom log file and process it.

```html
<appender name="CUSTOM_APP_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir}/custom-app.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir}/custom-app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- keep 3 custom log files worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%date~%level~%logger{40}~%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CUSTOM_APP_FILE" />
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks,  problem has solved with help of above solution